# Getting errors while updating records from another table : SQL Error: ORA-30926: unable to get a stable set of rows in the source tables

Tags: oracle11g, sql-merge

when I update historical records of one table dim from another table stg_v_a on the basis of ID, I get the following error:

Error report -

```
SQL Error: ORA-30926: unable to get a stable set of rows in the source tables
30926. 00000 -  "unable to get a stable set of rows in the source tables"
*Cause:    A stable set of rows could not be got because of large dml
           activity or a non-deterministic where clause.
*Action:   Remove any non-deterministic where clauses and reissue the dml.
```

The statement:

```
merge into dim dca
using (
  select ID,a_stat,a_ordl 
  FROM et.stg_v_a
) stg ON (stg.ID=dca.ID__V and dca.ad_st__v=stg.ad_st AND dca.ID__V is not null)
 when matched then update 
      set DCA.A_ORDL= stg.A_ORDL, DCA.a_updt_dt=sysdate;
```

Can any help me with this or suggest another method to do so?

Comment: Are you getting the error when it's been running for a while (suggesting the 'large DML activity' in the error might be to blame); or is it feasible that `stg_v_a` is a view that references `dim`?